# How do you model a curved boolean like this?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology

How do you model a curved boolean like this? [image]

Comment: Isn't there just a cylinder going through the U-beam? How did you get this result?

Comment: it was a step file which im going to remodell myself. the description here was the same way i tried my self. i think i failed with the mesh cleaning. ill give it a new try. thx. great community here!

Comment: Eh, I don't know how to title this... "How do you model a simple bottle opener"? :D

Comment: actually it is a piece of a crane arm...

Answer (score 1):

You could create 2 perpendicular faces, bevel the angle:

[image]

Cut a half-circle with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Clean the topology:

[image]

Cut the half-circle, give your object a *Mirror* and a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]